# Why does vague linkage seem to work for dynamically linked libraries using clang on MacOS but not using gcc on Linux?

Tags: c++, g++, clang, clang++

Here is some code I built and ran on Linux using gcc:

```
+ cat foo.h
#pragma once

inline int foo()
{
  static int static_local;
  return ++static_local;
}
+ cat lib.cc
#include "foo.h"

extern "C" void lib();

void lib()
{
  static_cast<void>(foo());
}
+ cat main.cc
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>

#include <dlfcn.h>

#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
  void *lib_handle = dlopen("./lib.a", RTLD_NOW);

  if (!lib_handle) {
    std::cout << "dlopen() failed: " << dlerror() << '\n';

    std::exit(1);
  }

  void *func = dlsym(lib_handle, "lib");

  if (func) {
    reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(func)();

  } else {
    const char *err = dlerror();

    if (!err) {
      std::cout << "lib() not found\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "dlsym() fail: " << err << '\n';
    }
  }

  // Should output 2.
  //
  std::cout << foo() << '\n';

  dlclose(lib_handle);

  return 0;
}
+ CMN_OPTS='-O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17'
+ cc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -DLIB -fPIC -c lib.cc
+ cc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -shared lib.o -o lib.a
+ cc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -c main.cc
+ cc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 main.o -lstdc++ -ldl -o main
+ ./main
1
```

Both lib.o and main.o should have a vague linkage section containing the static_local variable that's local to the foo() function.  This output indicates that vague linkage is not happening.  However, if I do the same thing on MacOS using clang, the output of main is 2, which indicates that the vague linkage **does** occur.  (The version of gcc is 8.3.1 and the version of clang is Apple 11.0.0.  The code files are at https://github.com/ywkaras/MiscRepo/tree/master/VagueDynLink .)

Comment: I tried a similar experiment within a large executable (Apache Trafficserver) built and run on Linux, and the vague linkage worked fine.  So it seems that there are unknown factors that contribute to this problem occurring.